# Comedy anime where the female lead is a ghost

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, ghost, urban-fantasy

I saw this anime at a friend's house one night during 2016 or 2017. I have been searching for it for the past three years but I was never able to find it. I have previously posted this onto both Reddit and MAL to no avail, and the friend in question could not remember its name either.

I remember it being a slice-of-life comedy shojo taking place in a high school where the main character was a shy teenage ghost girl who (possibly) made plants die when she touched them. She was most likely a western-inspired ghost and not a traditional Japanese/Chinese ghost/yokai/mononoke/jiangshi/ro-lang. The show had a non-stylized late 00's/early 10's post-Lucky-Star art style. The show did not focus much on how the lead died or why she was a ghost, just on character-character interactions and humor derived from her magical abilities.

I remember two specific scenes from what little I saw of it: One where where she hides under a concert stand polishing a skull during a school festival because she's too shy to perform (or something like that) and a secondary character tries to pull her out; and another where a male character is trying to clean the walls of their bathroom but keeps getting disinfectant in his eyes which turns into a non-canonical segment where a chibi version of the female lead teaches the audience why you should never spray disinfectant above eye level.

This anime is most likely not *Dusk Maiden of Amnesia*, but the design of the female lead is definitely closer to my memory than all the anime I have looked through so far. However, its style of animation and humor is significantly different from what I remember.  The anime I'm looking for did not have a horror-inspired art style, and did not sexualize the lead remotely as much (or at all, even).

It is DEFINITELY NOT:

- Ghost Hunt
- Ghost Stories
- Elegant Yokai Apartment Life
- Mieruko-chan
- Anohana
- Natsume's Book of Friends
- Ghost Hound
- Bakemonogatari
- Another
- Mushishi

I have only ever seen this anime for 30-50 minutes and my memory might not be entirely correct so please suggest anything that seems close. Also, I do not remember if the show was Chinese in origin. I only knew Chinese at that time and cannot remember whether or not the subtitles were turned on (it could also have been a Chinese dub).